# How to concatenate two or more vectors in Amardillo?

Tags: vector, concatenation, armadillo

For example, if I have

```
vec a(3, fill::randu);
vec b(5, fill::randu);
```

How can I get a new vector c of size 8, where the first three elements are from a and the rest from b?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `join_cols(a,b)` since `vec` inherits from `mat`

```
#include<armadillo>
using namespace arma;
int main()
{
     vec a(3, fill::randu);
     vec b(5, fill::randu);
     vec c;

     c = join_cols(a,b);
     a.print("a");
     b.print("b");
     c.print("a..b"); 
    return 0;
}
```

...gives the output

```
a
   0.8402
   0.3944
   0.7831
b
   0.7984
   0.9116
   0.1976
   0.3352
   0.7682
a..b
   0.8402
   0.3944
   0.7831
   0.7984
   0.9116
   0.1976
   0.3352
   0.7682
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the thing I want.